# Android Crashlytics Null Pointer excetion

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand why I get `NullPointerException`.

Here is Crashlytics report:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.roomapp.klassroom.sdk.model.KRPostEvent.getCoverThumbUrl()' on a null object reference
   at co.roomapp.klassroom.activity.KREventFormActivity.initUI + 150(KREventFormActivity.java:150)
   at co.roomapp.klassroom.activity.KREventFormActivity.onCreate + 101(KREventFormActivity.java:101)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7458(Activity.java:7458)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 7448(Activity.java:7448)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1286(Instrumentation.java:1286)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 3409(ActivityThread.java:3409)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 3614(ActivityThread.java:3614)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute + 86(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks + 108(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 68(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 2199(ActivityThread.java:2199)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 112(Handler.java:112)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 216(Looper.java:216)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7625(ActivityThread.java:7625)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 524(RuntimeInit.java:524)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 987(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

There is a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.roomapp.klassroom.sdk.model.KRPostEvent.getCoverThumbUrl()' on a null object reference`.

However you can see in my class the instance was created when the class is instantiated `KRPostEvent event = new KRPostEvent();`.

Anyone could be able to tell me how this variable event coule become null? Is it maybe due to life cycle? It should be a strong reference not collected by GC.

```
public class KREventFormActivity extends BaseActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    ImageView btnCamera;
    ImageView imgCover;
    TextView btnNext;

    EditText txtEventTitle;
    EditText txtEventLocation;
    EditText txtEventStart;
    EditText txtEventEnd;

    EditText txtEventDescription;
    Button btnDelete;

    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
    boolean editMode = false;
    KRPostEvent event = new KRPostEvent();
    KRPost post;
    KRKlass klass;

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    String filename;
    Bitmap savedImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_form);

        initVariables();
        initUI();
    }

    private void initVariables(){

        navigationHeaderView = (KRNavigationHeaderView) findViewById(R.id.navigationHeaderView);
        editMode = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("editMode",false);

        txtEventTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_txtEventTitle);
        txtEventLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_txtEventLocation);
        txtEventDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_txtEventDescription);
        txtEventStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_txtEventStart);
        txtEventEnd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_txtEventEnd);

        btnNext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_btnNext);
        btnCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_btnCamera);

        imgCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventForm_imgCover);
        btnDelete =  findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("event")) event = AppUtil.unserializeObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("event"), KRPostEvent.class);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("klassID") && getIntent().hasExtra("postID")){
            KRKlass k = KRClient.getInstance().getKlasses().get(getIntent().getStringExtra("klassID"));
            post = k.getPosts().get(getIntent().getStringExtra("postID"));
        }
    }

    private void initUI(){

        navigationHeaderView.lblTitle.setText((editMode)?R.string.str_title_event_edit:R.string.str_title_event_new);

        if(NavigationContoller.getInstance().isRoot(navigationName,this)){
            navigationHeaderView.enableCloseButton();
        }
        navigationHeaderView.setListener(new KRNavigationHeaderViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBack() {
                KREventFormActivity.this.onBack();
            }
        });


        if(event.getCoverThumbUrl() != null){
            Glide.with(this).load(event.getCoverThumbUrl()).fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.classroom).fitCenter().error(R.drawable.classroom).fitCenter().dontAnimate().into(imgCover);

        }else{
            if(event.getCoverImage() != null){
                imgCover.setImageBitmap(event.getCoverImage());
            }
        }

        txtEventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());
        txtEventDescription.setText(event.getDescription());
        txtEventLocation.setText(event.getLocation());

        if(event.getStartDate() != null){
            startDate = event.getStartDate();
            txtEventStart.setText( DateUtil.convertDateToPrettyString(startDate));
        }


        if(event.getEndDate() != null){
            endDate = event.getEndDate();
            txtEventEnd.setText( DateUtil.convertDateToPrettyString(endDate));
        }

        final TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener startTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND , 0);
                updateTextFieldStartDate();
            }
        };

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                new TimePickerDialog(KREventFormActivity.this, startTimePicker, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(KREventFormActivity.this)).show();
            }
        };

        txtEventStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(startDate != null){
                    myCalendar.setTime(startDate);
                }
                new DatePickerDialog(KREventFormActivity.this, startDatePicker, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

        final TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener endTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND , 0);
                updateTextFieldEndDate();
            }
        };

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener endDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                new TimePickerDialog(KREventFormActivity.this, endTimePicker, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(KREventFormActivity.this)).show();
            }
        };

        txtEventEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(endDate != null){
                    myCalendar.setTime(endDate);
                }
                new DatePickerDialog(KREventFormActivity.this, endDatePicker, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });


        btnDelete.setVisibility(post != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MessageDialog.showAlertMsg(KREventFormActivity.this, KREventFormActivity.this.getString(R.string.str_dialog_title_delete_post), KREventFormActivity.this.getString(R.string.str_dialog_content_delete_post), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        post.delete(new KRApiHandler(){
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                NavigationContoller.getInstance().dismiss(navigationName,KREventFormActivity.this);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        txtEventStart.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        txtEventEnd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        txtEventTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                KREventFormActivity.this.checkValid();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveEvent();
            }
        });

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImage();
            }
        });

        checkValid();
    }

    private void onBack(){
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        NavigationContoller.getInstance().pop(navigationName,this);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.noanim, R.anim.slide_up_leave);
    }

    private void checkValid(){
        if(txtEventTitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || startDate == null || endDate == null){
            btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void updateTextFieldStartDate(){
        checkValid();
        startDate = myCalendar.getTime();
        txtEventStart.setText( DateUtil.convertDateToPrettyString(startDate));
        checkValid();
    }

    private void updateTextFieldEndDate(){
        checkValid();
        endDate = myCalendar.getTime();
        txtEventEnd.setText( DateUtil.convertDateToPrettyString(endDate));
        checkValid();
    }

    private void saveEvent(){

        event.setTitle(txtEventTitle.getText().toString().trim());
        if(txtEventLocation.getText() != null) event.setLocation(txtEventLocation.getText().toString().trim());
        if(txtEventDescription.getText() != null) event.setDescription(txtEventDescription.getText().toString().trim());
        if(startDate != null) event.setStartDate(startDate);
        if(endDate != null) event.setEndDate(endDate);
        if(savedImage != null) event.setCoverImage(savedImage);

        if(post != null){

            MessageDialog.showAlertMsg(this, getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.remind_update_post),R.string.str_label_yes, R.string.str_label_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    _finish(true);
                }
            }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    _finish(false);
                }
            });

        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("event", event);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

            NavigationContoller.getInstance().pop(navigationName,this);
        }
    }

    private void _finish(boolean remind){

        if(remind){
            post.setRemindType(KRPostType.event);
        }else{
            post.setRemindType(null);
        }
        post.setEvent(event);
        if(post.getEvent() != null && post.getEvent().getCoverImage() != null){
            ProgressDlg.showProgressProcess(this,getString(R.string.str_guide_upload_event));
            ProgressDlg.pd.setMax(100);
        }

        btnNext.setEnabled(false);

        post.send(null, new KRApiHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                ProgressDlg.closeprocess(KREventFormActivity.this);
                NavigationContoller.getInstance().pop(navigationName,KREventFormActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(KRException e) {
                ProgressDlg.closeprocess(KREventFormActivity.this);
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                MessageDialog.showAlertMsg(KREventFormActivity.this, getString(R.string.str_title_error), e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(final long bytesWritten, final long totalSize) {
                KREventFormActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //ProgressDlg.pd.setMax((int)totalSize);
                        if(ProgressDlg.pd != null){
                            int prg = (int)(bytesWritten*1.0/totalSize*100);
                            ProgressDlg.pd.setProgress(0);
                            ProgressDlg.pd.setProgress(prg);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void addImage(){
        showTakePhotosDialog();

    }

    private void showTakePhotosDialog() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this,perms)){
            final CharSequence[] items = {this.getString(R.string.str_label_gallery), this.getString(R.string.str_label_camera), this.getString(R.string.str_label_cancel)};
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.str_guide_picture));
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (items[item] == getString(R.string.str_label_gallery)) {
                        chooseFromGallery();
                    }
                    if (items[item] == getString(R.string.str_label_camera)) {
                        takePhoto();
                    }
                    if (items[item] == getString(R.string.str_label_cancel)) {
                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }else{
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this,this.getString(R.string.str_guide_permission_camera),Constants.kPERMISSION_CAMERA_STORAGE,perms);
        }
    }

    private void chooseFromGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.kGALLERY);
    }

    public void takePhoto() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        filename = "IMG-" + (new Date()).getTime()+".jpg";
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, AppUtil.CacheUrifromFilename(this,filename));
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.kCAMERA);
    }


    //Delegate Photo
    public void didFinishTakingPicture(){
        Uri selectedImage = AppUtil.CacheUrifromFilename(this,filename);

        File source = AppUtil.getFile(KREventFormActivity.this,selectedImage);
        File f = AppUtil.moveImageToDir(KREventFormActivity.this, "Klassroom", source, KRUtils.getFlagForKey(Constants.FLAG_KEEP_LOCAL,true));

        String n = "TMP-"+f.getName();
        CropImage.activity(Uri.fromFile(f)).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setOutputCompressQuality(80).setOutputUri(AppUtil.CacheUrifromFilename(this,n)).start(this);

    }

    public void didSelectImagesFromGallery(Uri fileuri){
        if("content".equalsIgnoreCase(fileuri.getScheme())){
            String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(fileuri);

            if(mimeType.contains("image")) {
                Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(fileuri, null, null, null, null);
                returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                try {
                    InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileuri);
                    byte[] bytesArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                    KRFile f1 = new KRFile();
                    f1.setFileName(fileName);
                    f1.setMimeType("image");
                    f1.setData(bytesArray);

                    File f = f1.toFile();
                    String n = "TMP-"+f.getName();
                    CropImage.activity(Uri.fromFile(f)).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setOutputCompressQuality(80).setOutputUri(AppUtil.CacheUrifromFilename(this,n)).start(this);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }else{
                MessageDialog.showAlertMsg(this,getString(R.string.app_name),getString(R.string.str_dialog_content_cantimportfile));
            }

        }else{
            File f = AppUtil.getFile(this,fileuri);

            if(f.exists()) {
                String[] acceptedmim = {"jpg","jpeg","png"};
                boolean c = false;
                for(String s:acceptedmim){
                    if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.getPath()).toLowerCase().contains(s)){
                        c = true;
                    }
                }
                if(c) {
                    String n = "TMP-"+f.getName();
                    CropImage.activity(Uri.fromFile(f)).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setOutputCompressQuality(80).setOutputUri(AppUtil.CacheUrifromFilename(this,n)).start(this);
                }else{
                    MessageDialog.showAlertMsg(this,getString(R.string.app_name),getString(R.string.str_dialog_content_cantimportfile));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void didEditPhoto(final Uri imageUri)
    {

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                File f = AppUtil.getFile(KREventFormActivity.this,imageUri);
                try {
                    if(f != null && f.exists()) {
                        savedImage = Glide.with(KREventFormActivity.this).load(f).asBitmap().fitCenter().into(1280, 1280).get();

                        filename = null;

                        KREventFormActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imgCover.setImageBitmap(savedImage);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.kCAMERA:
                didFinishTakingPicture();
                break;
            case Constants.kGALLERY:
                didSelectImagesFromGallery(data.getData());
                break;
            case CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    didEditPhoto(result.getUri());
                } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
        if(requestCode == Constants.kPERMISSION_CAMERA_STORAGE){
            showTakePhotosDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is impossible error. But Java is known to show some impossible things sometimes. I have a case where `this` because `null` while calling a method, which looks even more impossible. So how frequently do you get such exception in crashlytics? Also which devices? Some devices may be running custom Java VMs, which could be customized the way they have some bugs and allow such impossible things.

Comment: `event = AppUtil.unserializeObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("event"), KRPostEvent.class);` might be null , and since `initVariables` called before `initUI` it might be risky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you declared it as

```
KRPostEvent event = new KRPostEvent();
```

But this call:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("event")) 
    event = AppUtil.unserializeObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("event"), KRPostEvent.class);
```

will reassign a new value to your `event` variable. In your case, a `null`.